# SCR switching conducted emissions

Tags: emc, switching, scr, emi-filtering

I have a circuit that drives a 240Vac line to line power to a resistive load. I am testing for radiated and conducted emissions. Radiated emissions went fine but conducted emissions failed with "broad band noise" on the power line (L1) in the 150Khz to 600Khz region.

The SCR switches at zero crossing point at 400Hz a 20A load, and I have input power filtering for EMI with some caps and common mode and differential mode inductance, as well as lightning protection.

[image: Conducted Emissions]

While trying some limited changes based on component availability I increased the capacitance across the lines, and the emissions got worse. Due to the 20A load, the highest differential mode inductors are 4.7uH. The input power goes to the SCRs and to a transformer that drives a 5V linear regulator.

[image: Input Power Filter]

What are things I can try to improve the conducted emissions?

UPDATE 1:
I create a simulation on LTSpice XVII to compare the FFT response to the 15 ohm resistor across all the inductors. I noticed quite a difference, and I would imagine it would have an impact but could I realistically correlate this oversimplification using FFT on all nodes? The numbers I played with were:
-replaced inductors from 4.7uH to 15uH
-added and removed 15 ohm resistor across all inductors

Since I do not have a way to physically measure without paying a lab, I would like to get a good indication that this could work. It seems changing to a 15uH and 15 ohm resistor created the cleanest FFT. Am I in the correct path?

[image: Original No Resistor]
[image: Original 4.7uH L with 15 ohm resistors]
[image: 15uH L update with 15 ohm resistors]
[image: 15uH L with 26 ohm resistors update]

[image]

Comment: when you changed the capacitors did CM or DM (or both) worsen. Also what are you driving the SCR with?

Comment: Which capacitors did you experiment with? recognize you've got a PI filter here; with NO losses, you'll have horrific peaking. The Q=1 ?? resistance is sqrt(L/C). sqrt(4.7uh / 0.022uf) = sqrt(200) = 15 ohms. Try 15 ohms (1 watt?) across the 4.7uh.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf I agree, there needs to be some damping. This energy needs to be dissipated somewhere.  400Hz sounds aerospace/nautical.

Comment: And resistors ACROSS the 4.7uH do not increase the low frequency losses, correct?

Comment: You may need to use much larger inductor's to avoid L/C time-constants that cause peaking. Try to keep L over 300 uH, even though it will be physically large. At 1.5 mH you could stop a 10 Ka lightning surge. You are thinking of minimum inductance (for size reasons?), when you should be thinking of the maximum size inductor rated for 20 amps that will fit your design.

Comment: I’m using the 4.7uH because that is the biggest inductor I could find off the shelf rated for 20A. The caps I played with was updating the both 22nF to a 0.33uF.  And the 1nF tons 2.2nF that I just happen to have with me.

Comment: The SCR is being driven by a Zero Cross opto TRIAC. The load are purely resistive load. The output to the load has the same 4.7uH inductor going and coming back from the load with the same 22nF Cx Cap across the lines to the load. If I add a resistor across the inductors, what kind of voltage rating should I go for?

Comment: Update 1: Added a 15 ohm resistor to a simulation and I am trying to use the FFT function of LTSpice to see impact. Would this be a good approach to derive possible outcome